# Room persistence library with Gradle 4.1 issue

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle

I tried to use Room persistence library in my project, so I added this
to build.gradle (project):

```
allprojects {
 repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
  }
}
```

and this code to build.gradle (module):

```
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
testImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.0.0"
```

here is the whole dependencies module:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
testImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.0.0"
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
```

}

but every time I try to sync Gradle it's loading very long time and finally I get a problem like:

**Gradle sync failed: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip'.**

Comment: Can you post grade errors from the console.

Comment: I get only : Gradle sync failed: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip' 
in the console.

Comment: Do check your `gradle.properties` file in root drictory of the project under gradle folder and wrapper

Comment: There are couple of them. In one of them there is: `# in $HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties
java6Home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
`. Maybe it should use newer version of jdk..

Comment: I found that I'm not the only person with such problem: [https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62473121]

Comment: I have this line in my `gradle-wrapper.properties` under `/rootProjectdir/gradle/wrapper` 
the 
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions-snapshots/gradle-4.4-20171031235950+0000-all.zip`

This is the url from which gradle downloads the wrapper, can you check yours?

Comment: In my `gradle-wrapper.properties` it looks like that: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip`